# Django Custom User form : Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

I am using Django(2.0.7) UserCreationForm with three extra fields namely- first_name, last_name and email. I am getting the following error in the terminal window when I signup a new user (Though the user is created).

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username


return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username
```

My forms.py is

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    alphabetic = RegexValidator(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$')
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email Address', }))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name', 'style': 'text-transform:capitalize'}),
                                 validators=[alphabetic])
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=254, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'style': 'text-transform:capitalize'}),
                                validators=[alphabetic])

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        widgets = {'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Choose a Password'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Confirm the Password'})

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
```

I have also tried overriding the default save method in the form, but that didn't work either. I have deleted my db multiple times and created fresh db but none has helped so far.

I am using a login modal in bootstrap. So my views.py is some what like this:-

```
def register_view(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = SignupForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('signup.html',
                                         context,
                                         request=request
                                         )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I have also tried adding the following lines in my settings.py :-

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup':'accounts.forms.SignupForm',}

Comment: "sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username" says that there already exists an user (in the table auth_user) with the same username.
So maybe the user isn't created, but it is the already existing one?

Comment: No, I am creating a new user for sure. But I have added a print statement, and I assume that register_view is running twice because if i add print("Yes") after form.is_valid(), "yes" is printed twice on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will happen

```
form.save(commit=False)
```